# How I can select specific platform in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My question is very simple, how can i launch an environment with a **64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.7** in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Elastic Beanstalk service supports a variety of platforms options, available as part of the service itself, which can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html).

Elastic Beanstalk also support custom platforms, which you can build yourself. You can read more about creating custom platforms for your Elastic Beanstalk application [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html).